# Cloud foundry Error : Array.includes is not a function

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I am trying to traverse through an array returned by `fs` library in my node.js application. In my local machine the following code is working fine:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = fs.readdirSync("<directory>");
if(data.includes('a')){
    console.log('value found!');
}
```

But when I uploaded my same application in CloudFoundry, i got the error as:

```
Error: data.includes is not a function
```

can anyone explain what could be the reason for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Includes" doesn't work with Node 5.x So,please check node version.In order to make it work in current version.just follow below code.or you upgrade node to version 6.

```
if(data.indexOf('a')> -1){
    console.log('value found!');
}
```